# Laravel Passport- how to register new user

Tags: laravel, oauth, laravel-passport

I have two projects:

**App1**: Users currently log into this application.

**App2**: An API which some users of App1 will get access to.

I am using Laravel Passport and initially the password grant type.
It is working OK, using Postman and I can get an access_token.

What I don't understand is how the users credentials get into **App2**. I get that I can add a register route that creates the user record but how is this done securely? What stops anyone from hitting this endpoint and creating a user record?

Comment: Creating a secure token on App1 and validating certain requests are coming from App1 using that token on App2, is a basic way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want app1 to be responsible for authentication (among other things) and app2 to only accept users authenticated on app1.

I can think of two scenarios to get the user in app2:

First approach:

Whenever a user is registered on app1, send a request from app1 to app2 to register the user in app2 for the user to be able to use app2 later. Secure the request so that only app1 can make it to app2 (maybe using ssl encryption or any other way).

Second Approach:

Add a login route on app2 that expects a token from app1. When called, app2 would take the token and call app1 for user info and to authenticate their access to app2 Then register user's info and issue a new token from app2 to be used later on it's apis. Hence, no registeration route will be used on app2 but only login either through a token from app1 (to register user) or later using a token from app2.